# Delete older users by role

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make a script for WORDPRESS that can delete users by role (example "subscribers") that are older than 20 days. I searched for a plugin but I cant find any.

I have found this script that deletes users by role but I want to delete the users that are older than 20 days with a same role.

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( './wp-load.php' );

$role = "subscriber"; // The role to kill
$reassign = 1; // The user that all posts will fall back to, other wise they will be deleted

$this_role = "[[:<:]]$role[[:>:]]";

$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELEC T user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities' AND meta_value RLIKE %s", $this_role );

if ( $users_of_this_role = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_N ) )
    foreach ( $users_of_this_role as $user_id )
            wp_delete_user( $user_id[0], $reassign );
```

Comment: can't you add in the query `$query` a date/time field as well? I don't know wordpress' db structure but I'm sure it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a SELECT inside a WHERE clause will help you achieve what you're looking for (delete users older than X amount of days).
Adjust code according to your needs (read inline comments for explanation). After, create a file in your plugins' folder and name it delete_users.php. Then add the following code inside, save, and activate it as a plugin from the WP Dashboard.

> delete_users.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Delete old users
 * Plugin URI: http://stackoverflow.com/users/395160/manolis
 * Description: Delete users older than x amount of days
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Manolis
 * Author URI: http://stackoverflow.com/users/395160/manolis
 * License: GPL2
 */

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

global $wpdb;
require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/user.php');

$role = "author"; // The role to kill
$reassign = 1; // The user that all posts will fall back to, other wise they will be deleted
$days = 20; // Calculated in days, how old a user should be in order to get deleted

$this_role = "[[:<:]]".$role."[[:>:]]";

$query = $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT user_id
    FROM $wpdb->usermeta
    WHERE meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities'
    AND (SELECT user_id 
            FROM $wpdb->users 
            WHERE user_registered < NOW() - INTERVAL $days DAY
         )
    AND meta_value RLIKE %s", $this_role);


if ( $users_of_this_role = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_N ) )
    foreach( $users_of_this_role as $user_id )
        wp_delete_user( $user_id[0], $reassign );

?>
```